# How to reduce loading time of sql query?

Tags: mysql, performance, laravel-5, eloquent

I had created a query to get a list of staffs using this query. It is run after checked the permission level of the login user.

```
  if (Auth::user()->hasPermissionTo('All Sections')) {

  $itemregistrations = DB::table('itemregistrations')
                       ->join('sections', 'itemregistrations.sectionid', '=', 'sections.sectionid')
                       ->join('categories', 'itemregistrations.categoryid', '=', 'categories.categoryid')
                       ->join('operasi', 'itemregistrations.operasiid', '=', 'operasi.operasiid')
                       ->select('itemregistrations.ItemRegistrationID','itemregistrations.name', 'itemregistrations.Nobadan', 'sections.sectionname', 'categories.categoryname', 'operasi.operasiname')
                       ->get();
```

}

However, the query gets loading quite long, about a minute to finish loading. The list displayed about 1115.

How to reduce the loading time?

I read about eager loading to decrease the loading time. But my trial not success.

section is the department of staffs.

categories is the staff level

operasi is the grade of staff, related to categories, each category has its own operasiname.

This is the indexing on itemregistrations table.

[image]

I had installed laravel debugger and produce this result:
-6 views
-4 queries

```
  select * from `users` where `id` = 1 limit 1

  select `permissions`.*, `model_has_permissions`.`model_id` as `pivot_model_id`, `model_has_permissions`.`permission_id` as 
  `pivot_permission_id` from `permissions` 
  inner join `model_has_permissions` on `permissions`.`id` = `model_has_permissions`.`permission_id` 
  where `model_has_permissions`.`model_id` = 1 and `model_has_permissions`.`model_type` = 'App\User'

  select `roles`.*, `model_has_roles`.`model_id` as `pivot_model_id`, `model_has_roles`.`role_id` as `pivot_role_id` from `roles` 
  inner join `model_has_roles` on `roles`.`id` = `model_has_roles`.`role_id` 
  where `model_has_roles`.`model_id` = 1 and `model_has_roles`.`model_type` = 'App\User'

  select `itemregistrations`.`ItemRegistrationID`, `itemregistrations`.`name`, 
   `itemregistrations`.`Nobadan`, `sections`.`sectionname`, `categories`.`categoryname`, `operasi`.`operasiname` 
   from `itemregistrations` inner join `sections` on `itemregistrations`.`sectionid` = `sections`.`sectionid` 
   inner join `categories` on `itemregistrations`.`categoryid` = `categories`.`categoryid` 
   inner join `operasi` on `itemregistrations`.`operasiid` = `operasi`.`operasiid`
```

-1116 gates

The above query is filtered according to few permissions.

these are indexes for table involved:

1. role table index

[image: role index]

2. permission table index
   [image: permission]
3. model has role table
   [image]
4. role has permission table

[image]

Comment: Please provide the generated `SELECT` statement and `SHOW CREATE TABLE` for each table.

Answer (score 1):

for the DB side  be sure you have proper index  on the columns involved in JOIN

```
sections sectionid
categories categoryid
operasi operasiid
```

expecially  a composite index  on

```
itemregistrations   (sectionid , categoryid , operasiid )
```

anyway  the load  of 1256 si pretty unuseful  in real app ..
for this you could reduce the loading time for the data show using pagination

based on you cardinality  you should build an index

itemregistrations   (operasiid, sectionid , categoryid )

could be you need  remove the index  on the same columns involved  and leave only the composite ...

Comment: I load it and display it using datatable in blade.. I already try pagination and decrease load but it is not compatible for datatable ..

Comment: What do you mean with proper index?

Comment: be sure you have the index  on your table  .. and expecially a composite index on the table  itemregistrations     that use the 3 columns mentioned

Comment: I have updated my question with indexing view..is it right?

Comment: you have each column in a separated  index .. this is pretty unuseful for you goal .. you should use an index  that involve the 3 column you use in ON clause  ..  writing the cols name left to right based  on the high cardinality ..  i have updated  the answer

Comment: I already remove the individual index and leave only composite, but it still loading about 20seconds++

Comment: 1123 rows in the table

Comment: you are able to show me the sql query that is actually generated?  and show me also the indexes related  to the other tables involved

Comment: actually the query is guarded with permission level..that's why in the query from debugger has permission and role table involved

Comment: But the time you signed  (about a minute) is related only at the result for items registration query or is related  to all the query you added  .. ???

Comment: then you should check for each single query  the time  .could be that the index  already provided  improve  one query  (the query you asked  at the begin)  but there are others query that slow done the performance ..

Comment: just asking, by using eloquent relationship, can it reduce no of queries from the current one?

Comment: I don't understand why accessing  at itemregistrations  all the query related  to roles and permission are involved ..  and i'm not expert of eloquent but the check for permission  is done just one time or is done each time for arch itemregistration rows? .. could be that eloquent make available some function for direct query not based on active record  ..

Comment: thank you for your feedback... I will check further.